# Importing database into mysql causes 0 rows in tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, import, phpmyadmin

I'm transferring a wordpress website from one server to another (same host). I've exported the website from one server using phpmyadmin, and imported it on the other server using phpmyadmin as well. Import is successful, but when viewing the database, it shows me that there are 0 rows in all of the tables. The size of the tables isn't zero, but it's less than the original. I've attached an example screenshot.
Original:
[http://imgur.com/download/Dn6KEfS](https://imgur.com/download/Dn6KEfS)

Imported:
[http://imgur.com/download/cOEPTcV](https://imgur.com/download/cOEPTcV)

Both servers are nginx/1.4.6,libmysql - 5.5.53, with mysqli php extension. I've tried the following:
* Importing and exporting with Update instead Insert statements
* Dropping the tables in the new database multiple times and reimporting
* Using command line tools instead of phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Anyone that stumbles upon this:
- Before the exporting I had an issue with some of the tables, I would aways get an issue of key already exists in "_transient", etc. I don't know if this was a caching issue or something, but I read that using UPDATE instead of INSERT would fix the issue, so I exported the SQL database with UPDATE set instead of INSERT.

- Coming from a lot of update_post_meta in wordpress, I incorrectly assumed that SQL would insert a row with the update statement if it doesn't exist, which is not the case. That is why my tables were created, but they were empty because there was nothing to update.
- So the solution is: I exported the database with INSERT statements, I didn't include tables that were giving me issues, and I used the command line, instead of phpmyadmin interface to import the database. This is because I sometimes have an unreliable connection and uploading a big file might cause an issue. So I uploaded it first through rsync, then use

  mysql> use database;

  mysql> source exported_db.sql

Hopefully this will save some hours of life to someone.